# I don't know the accents for French words & I want to pass the B1 DELF exam (production écrite)

Tags: grammaire

I don't know the accents for French words, and I would like to pass the B1 DELF exam. How important are the errors related to the accents for the grading of *production écrite*? I searched online, but didn't find any information about it.

For example, if all the accents are missing for the *production écrite*, how many points will I lose?

Comment: Accentuation is important in French. The meaning of a sentence could be pretty different with or without accents.

Comment: If you know what a French word sounds like, and you distinguish between the vowels é and è, you can guess the accents on the e's fairly accurately (except for the accent circonflexe, ê, which is often related to the historical spelling, and for that you can often deduce the presence of a circonflexe if the English cognate has an "s" that the French is missing).

Comment: I don't know about the grading, but missing a diacritic is as much of a mistake as missing a letter in a word.

Comment: Have you consulted the DELF website itself?  They are going to have more information about their own test prep.  We are not a test prep site.

Comment: @livresque: Yes, I consulted it, but I didn't find the information I need.

Comment: This [chart](http://www.delfdalf.fr/_media/grille-evaluation-production-ecrite-delf-b1.pdf) (from an unofficial website) gives 2x 2pts for spelling, out of 25pts. Beyond the exam, accents are a must-have in many aspects - at least socially, sometimes even to be understood at all. Chances are that inability to accentuate words will also affect your spoken French.

Comment: @guillaume31: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was searching for.